# How to open a zip file in a CD from silverlight control in Silverlight 2.0 Application?

Tags: silverlight, cd

We have a silverlight application from which we are trying to open a zip file which is placed in a CD.Can any one tell how to open .zip files from local path of CD from SilverLight control.

Thanks & regards,
Sheetal

Answer (score 3):

In order to access a file without user intervention, you need to use [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage(VS.95).aspx).

To access a file outside of isolated storage, you need to use an [open file dialog](http://www.silverlightexamples.net/post/Open-File-Dialog-in-Silverlight.aspx).